# WebGPU - has it already been officially adopted?

Tags: webgpu

Please explain, I still could not understand - the WebGPU standard - has it already been officially adopted?

There is still not much information on the Internet about this.

Comment: [Implementation Status: Work in Progress](https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb/wiki/Implementation-Status)

Comment: [Can I Use webgpu](https://caniuse.com/webgpu)? All major browser engines are working on implementing this spec.

Comment: As you can see in [their recent meeting](https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb/wiki/%23-GPU-Web-meeting-2022-11-09-10-APAC-timed), there is still a lot of implementation and issue discussion going on.

Comment: @DanielW. I just wanted to mention that it's not only for browsers but also very promising for portable (in terms of the code) native apps/games thanks to [wgpu](https://wgpu.rs/) and other libs.

Comment: @Daniel W, the question is, can it happen that in some future versions the WebGPU API will change?

Comment: How strict can we answer this question?

Comment: @DanielW. - not sure what you mean by "how strict" but the question itself is off-topic here.

Comment: It's not necessarily off-topic, it's just very poorly researched because the answer is right at their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every API aims to not change but there is no guarantuee, especially when the status is work in progress / draft.

WebGPU in browsers: https://caniuse.com/webgpu

Implementation Status: https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb/wiki/Implementation-Status

---

Current status from https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/

#### WebGPU

Editor’s Draft, 13 November 2022

#### What is an Editor's draft?

> Software MAY implement these drafts at their own risk. Implementation
> is neither discouraged nor encouraged but can contribute to proposals
> for further action on a specification.

> An Editor's Draft is a document that W3C has not yet published and the
> group responsible for the draft may publish eventually.

https://www.w3.org/standards/types#ED

---